# block device mappings for Amazon aws/ec2 images

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto

I have two related questions - or problems - with the Amazon ec2 API.
While I really want to use python and the boto package and that's how I
present the code below, I get exactly the same results with the
equivalent shell ec2-* commands.

First, I want to spawn an instance from a Debian based public AMI image,
but I want a larger root "partition" (because I want to install extra
Debian packages which are not in the image).  The documentation led me
to believe I should do something like this:

```
import boto.ec2 as BE
import boto.ec2.blockdevicemapping as BEM

conn=BE.connect_to_region('us-east-1')
bdt=BEM.BlockDeviceType()
# I want a 10G root device, not a 1G 
bdt.size=10
bdm=BEM.BlockDeviceMapping()
bdm['/dev/sda1']=bdt
reservations=conn.run_instances('ami-1234abcd', key_name='mykey',
                                instance_type='m1.medium', block_device_map=bdm)
```

However, this seems to have absolutely no effect.  The instance is spawned fine,
correct image and everything, but the root device is still just 1G :-(

So, then I thought maybe I need to somehow initialize the BlockDeviceMapping from the
image before I modify it.  I tried it like this:

```
bdm=conn.get_image_attribute('ami-1234abcd', attribute='blockDeviceMapping')
```

and this results in some strange exception trace saying 'Attempted
unauthorized operation' or similar.  And this happens even for an image
that I myself created by freezing another instance!

It is easy enough to modify the device configuration when creating an
instance in the horrible web interface.  Please show me how to do so
programatically!  Thanks.

Comment: Did you try resizing the filesystem after starting the instance?

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks correct.

Try using your same code to start an Ubuntu AMI (you can find them all here: http://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/locator/ec2/)

When an Ubuntu AMI starts, it will look at the root block device. If the device is larger than the root filesystem, it will automatically resize the root filesystem to fill the root block device. No fuss - everything else works the same.

This is almost always what you want to happen.

If it works for Ubuntu, at least you know your code is correct. Then you just need to figure out how to resize a Debian rootfs (or just use Ubuntu).